# Encrypt text and save to text file. Also read and decrypt - Java

Tags: java, encryption, text

I am trying to encrypt a string using my own password key. 
After generate encrypted text i need to save it to text file to later use. Also i need to read that encrypted text end decrypt it. It will be great if some one can give me a solution to do this thing in Java SE App.

Comment: "It will be great if some one can give me a solution to do this thing in Java SE App" - Sorry, thats not going to happen.

Comment: Take a look into the ```java.crypto``` packages. There's a good place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about Spring's TextEncryptor.  Its not strictly SE but it might still be good enough for your use case.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.Encryptors;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.TextEncryptor;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        TextEncryptor te = Encryptors.text("12345abc", "1234"); //password, salt.... in hex
        File file = new File("someFile.txt");
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
        String encryptedText = te.encrypt("hellow world!");
        fw.append(encryptedText);
        fw.close();

        String text = IOUtils.toString(new FileInputStream(file));
        System.out.println(te.decrypt(text));

    }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

The cipher-descipher is very simple, the concept is the following one: Message - function - cipher Message. The function (that it contains the password) can choose one of the existent (complicated and insecure) ones or to invent it your same one. The function should complete that it is inyectiva and sobreyectiva and the treatment will be a XOR between the message and the function. The descipher is the inverse of this process. The secret this in the function that you have chosen (password). To see the principles of Kerckhoffs and one-time pad of Vernam, Shannon. I also recommend you to see some java book that speaks of FILE I/O.